# PHP dot remove from checksum

Tags: php, string

Im trying to generate barcode and i need to remove dots from my invoice checksum.
Barcode requires that checksum must be in 8 numbers. checksum and others are zeros.

If the checksum is 35.88
Barcode number must be 00003588

And if checksum is 296.55
Barcode must be 00029655

How do i do that? All I have is this right now:

```
str_replace(".", "", $string);
```

But how can I get the zeros in the front of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo str_pad(str_replace('.', '', '35.88'), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 00003588
```

To remove everything but not numbers:

```
str_pad(preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", 'a35b.88c'), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 00003588
```

Comment: thank you and what would be the code if you want to remove all other things including dots but not numbers?

Comment: added a version which removes everything but not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you have a choice *:-)* [**demo**](http://ideone.com/d0Mz9U):

```php
sprintf('%08s', filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
```